# How to create topographical contour lines ?

Tags: node-editor, geometry

I am working on engraved cave walls, got from 3D scan. I would like to create topographical contour lines (maybe not "lines" but "ranges" ...) in order to see better the engravings.

I have already managed to display what is front from what is back with Geometry/Pointiness node, but i would like to be able to enter accurate values for each slice ... Like 0-3mm, 3-6mm ...

Does anyone know how to do this ?

*(sorry if my english is not quite good)*

[image: My first try for displaying contour-lines]

Comment: What you probably want to do is a modified version of the old method of simulating fog only with a different colormap. So in old versions of blender you could use the compositor to simulate fog by taking distance from camera and mapping that to a blend value with a solid color like gray. Here you would uses material nodes with the color determined by a colorband whose input is the z coordinate position.

Comment: You could do this using the Seperate XYZ node and a color-ramp

Comment: couldn't you just use global coordinates to test how high it is on the Y axis or what ever your normal is pointing to